# Knockout Validtion - Hide error messages

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application, knockout-validation

I never want any error messages to appear on the view (I am using toastr to display errors generated by knockout validation).  In my code, I am using: insertMessages: false.  That suppresses errors UNLESS the user enters data in a required field, removes that data, and then tabs out of the control. I can't figure out how to hide any error messages when the user tabs out of the input control.  Here is my code excerpts-

viewmodel-

```
 LCAmount: ko.observable(LCAmount).extend({ insertMessages: false, required: { message: 'LC Amount is Required' } })

        var saveAll = function () {
        try {

            var goAhead = true;
            var changes = false;

            SaveFlag(true);

              ko.utils.arrayForEach(LoanDetails(), function (item) {


                if (item.LCAmount != '') 
                    changes = true;


                if (item.errors().length > 0) {
                    goAhead = false;
                    logError("Errors on form: " + item.errors(), item, true);
                }

            });

                 if (goAhead && changes && okStoSave) {
                $.prompt("Are you sure you want to save? You will not be able to change your decision after it's been saved.", {
                    title: "Save?",
                    buttons: { "Save": true, "Cancel": false },
                    submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
                        if (v) {
                            response = saveUpdates(LoanDetails);

                            });

                            vm.clientNumber('');
                            vm.clientName('');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

VIEW-

```
  <input data-bind="value: LCAmount, validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }" />
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your input in a container like a div and apply the validationOptions to that.

```
<div data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }"><input data-bind="value: LCAmount" /></div>
```

Comment: Not sure why I received a down vote, I had to do this to make it work in my application.

Comment: This worked for me, but not when I tried to put it on a parent that happened to use the template binding. Had to add an extra wrapper inside the template.